# Mongodb insert lines from growing csv file in collection

Tags: mongodb, csv

I am trying to read a comma-separated CSV file and load into mongodb collection. The CSV file is continuously growing (adding new lines at end) with very high rate, lets say ~100 lines per seconds where line size is approximate 200 characters. It is ok if the operation is asynchronous but should not lock the file for any reason. My CSV file will be something like,

```
A001,John,male,20,Y
A002,Peter,male,22,N
A003,Mary,female,20,N,
A004,Katy,female,21,Y
```

And I want to insert in collection with fixed field names like,

```
db.test20sep.insert({
  id:"A001",
  name: "John",
  sex: "male",
  age: 20,
  present:"Y"  
})
```

Please suggest me most efficient approach. Please note, i also have to make live dashboard based on this collection's data so there multiple queries shall be firing on collection.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a "stream". Which language? Should not really be to difficult to find a "stream parser" for CSV for your language of choice, now you know what to look for.

Comment: I am using Node.js and angular

Comment: There are parsers available they work on static file but my file is continuously  growing .